# extracting ith and ith+1 from random 2D numpy array

Tags: python

I have a numpy array consisting of

```
[1,3,8,6,0,2,4,5,9,7]
```

This array is a random array consisting of 10 numbers 0-9.

I also have a 2D numpy array, a 10X10 2D numpy array with numerical values.

I would like to use my 1D numpy array (above) to access specific instances in my 2D numpy array, by looping through the 1D array

1. Loop 1: takes in 1 and 3, and finds the value at [1:3] in my 2D numpy array.
2. Loop 2: takes in 3 and 8, and finds the value at [3:8] in my 2D numpy array.

.

10. Loop 10: takes in 7 and 1, and finds the value at [7:1] in my 2D numpy array.

I would like to add up these values in my 2D numpy array.

so far I have :
array=[1,3,8,6,0,2,4,5,9,7]

```
values =0
for i in range (0, len(array)): #this is 10
    a=array2[i,array[i]+1]  #array2 is the 2D numpy array with the values
    values=values+a
```

This works to some degree but how to I get it to access the last element to the first? i.e. find [7,1]

Comment: Won't loop 10 be 9 and 7? Why do you wrap around and consider 7 and 1? Also, your array contains 11 numbers from 0-10.

Comment: my apologies, I will fix this now

Comment: Ok. See my answer. As far as I think, you don't need a for loop. That will make things only slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple slicing to make this work.

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,10))
pos = np.array([1,3,8,6,0,2,4,5,9,7])
pos = np.append(pos, pos[0])

rows = pos[0:-1]
cols = pos[1:]

result = sum(arr[rows, cols])
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. I hope it is okay I ask some questions on this, please: Is this just finding the value at [7,1]?

Comment: oh sorry, what I am doing is taking the first value of the array and appending it at the end. So if the first element was 2 and the last element was 7, then it would append 2 at the end and take the value at [7,2]. I corrected it now.

Comment: I understand- Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the slicing twice to make it work.

```
values = 0
for i in range(len(array)): 
    a = Matrix[array[i],array[i+1]]
    values += a
```

Also, the array you put has 11 elements which means the 10-th loop will not be what you intended.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so fast. I will try this now :)

Comment: This seems to work but only for the issue of using  "array[i+1] " on the final entry in the 1D array. I am getting an error "index 15 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 15"- thank you so much for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood what you were trying to achieve but... 
What about something like this?

```
a = np.array([1,3,8,6,0,9,2,4,5,9,7])
b = np.array(range(100)).reshape(10,10)

for i in range (len(a)):
    print (a[i%len(a)],a[(i+1)%len(a)])
    print (b[a[i%len(a)],a[(i+1)%len(a)]])
```

I removed 10 from the `a` array to avoid an index out of range error.

I also took the value [x,y] (and not the range [x:y] from the 2D array.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so fast. I will try this now :)